# if (condition || condition) vs if (condition) if (condition)

Tags: java, if-statement

I just started the project Euler and I already have some problems.
why do these methods produce different results?

```
int sum=0;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(i%3==0 || i%5==0)
    sum+=i;
}
```

**vs**

```
int sum=0;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(i%3==0)
   sum+=i;
if (i%5==0)
   sum+=i;
}
```

Comment: What if `i` is divisible by both 3 and 5? What does your second code do?

Comment: What happens when i is 15?

Comment: Might be a good time to learn to debug https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one will look if it is either i%3 or i%5.
Even if both are true, it only executes it once.

The seconde one, will execute sum+=i twice, if both are true:

```
30%3 = 0 and 30%5 = 0
```

So both of these will be executed:

```
if(i%3==0)
   sum+=i;
if (i%5==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first, it is sufficient that any of the comparisons be true to execute the sentence. If the first comparison is true, the second comparison will no longer be made. This is because True or [boolean] is always true. That is, it is enough that in the sequence of comparisons joined by or there is a true one, then the result will always be true.

In the second, the two conditions are always evaluated. And depending on those evaluations the sentences will be executed or not.